# SUM IFS across multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries in SQL:

Query A:

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 FROM a
```

Query B

```
SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 FROM b
```

I want to add another column in `a` such that the column represent the SUM of all values from b.column_3 where b.column_1 = a.column_1

How can this be done in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all rows you needed:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b -- left join because for some of the rows in "a" there will be not row in "b"
    ON a.column_1 = b.column_1 -- your first condition
    OR a.column_2 = b.column_2 -- your second condations
```

Then we just need to perform the sum:

```
SELECT a.column_1
      ,a.column_2
      ,a.column_3
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN b.column_1 IS NOT NULL AND a.column_1 = b.column_1 THEN b.column_3 ELSE 0 END)
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN b.column_1 IS NOT NULL AND a.column_2 = b.column_2 THEN b.column_3 ELSE 0 END)
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b 
    ON a.column_1 = b.column_1 
    OR a.column_2 = b.column_2 
GROUP BY a.column_1
        ,a.column_2
        ,a.column_3
```

Comment: The OP has changed its question several times since the original post, and since others have answered.  I would have suggested that you _not_ post this answer.

Answer (score 0):

A join with aggregation should work here:

```
SELECT
    a.column_1,
    a.column_2,
    a.column_3,
    b.b_sum
FROM a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT column_1, SUM(column_3) AS b_sum
    FROM b
    GROUP BY column_1
) b
    ON a.column_1 = b.column_1;
```

Comment: How to do it when there are two conditions on the sum ifs? For example: b.b_sum is the sum of all values from b.column 3 where b.column_1 = a.column_1 and b.column_2 = a.column_2?

I can do this no problem with excel but with the number of rows i am doing, the program is just so slow. Trying to do it in SQL now though thinking that it would be faster

Comment: Nice.  I have answered your original question, and I will not sit here with you and iterate as you keep changing your question.  You should open a new question if you have other requirements.